# Need to extract specific values from JSON String in selenium java

Tags: java, json, selenium

example json

```
String response = 
"{
"data":{
"getData":[
{
"key1":"value1"
"key2":"value2"
"key3":"value3"
},
{
"key1":"value11"
"key2":"value21"
"key3":"value31"
}
]
}
}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String str= jsonObject.getString("key3");
```

im getting below error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["key3"] not found.
```

pls help how to get value of key3 with two diff values - value3 and value31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve `key3` you need to go to the nested objects:

```
String response = "{\n" +
                "    \"data\": {\n" +
                "        \"getData\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"key1\": \"value1\",\n" +
                "                \"key2\": \"value2\",\n" +
                "                \"key3\": \"value3\"\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"key1\": \"value11\",\n" +
                "                \"key2\": \"value21\",\n" +
                "                \"key3\": \"value31\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("getData");
int length = jsonArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("key3"));
}
```